# C program to read characters is supposed to stop at newline, but isn't stopping

Tags: c

I have to develop a program that reads characters from the keyboard and write them on screen. However if the character entered is a lowercase letter than it must be converted to an uppercase letter. The reading finishes´after a line (when we press the ENTER key).

My attempt:

```
int main(void)
{
    char c;
    printf("Please enter characters. Press ENTER when you are finished\n");

    do
    {
        scanf(" %c", &c);
        if (c<='z' && c>='a')
            c= c-32;

        printf("%c\n", c);
    } while(c!='\n');
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, the program never ends and I don't how do I do that. I'm also not sure if, even though if I insert like 5 characters and the program prints them, if this is the correct form to program it. A character is a character, a single character, it seems to me that it doesn't make much sense that it reads and prints five characters.

Can someone explain what's wrong?

Comment: You should probably use the `toupper()` function from the `<ctype.h>` header, possibly with `islower()`, though it isn't absolutely necessary.  You should also test the return value from `scanf()`; if it isn't 1, you should break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In `while(c!='\n');`, `'\n'` is a special whitespace character which is ignored by `scanf` and thus you will never read it. To terminate you need to specify a terminating character. For example "stop if user enters character x"
then the terminating condition should be `while(c!='x');`

Comment: In the context of the `scanf(" %c", &c)`, the blank ignores white space, meaning blanks, tabs and (in particular) newlines.  That means you will never get a newline returned by the `scanf()`.  You've over-stated your case; the newline is not always ignored by `scanf()` — it terminates numeric input, for example — but it is skipped when the format string contains a space (or tab or newline).  It is hard to describe `scanf()` behaviour accurately and succinctly — it is a frustrating function for novices to learn.  In its simplest modes, it works well, but there are so many ways to get confused.

Answer (score 0):

`char` can only get one character. So if you want to end your loop you can use like `while (c != '0');`
For uppercase letter you can use `toupper()` function from `<ctype.h>` Library

Answer (score 0):

explanation of what is wrong with the following code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char c;
    printf("Please enter characters. Press ENTER when you are finished\n");

    do
    {
        scanf(" %c", &c);
        if (c<='z' && c>='a')
            c= c-32;

        printf("%c\n", c);
    } while(c!='\n');
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

1. missing the statement:  `#include <stdio.h>`
2. call to `scanf()` has space before `%c` which causes `white space` to be consumed/discarded and space, tab, newline are all white space
3. calculation of uppercase is not desirable.  Much better to simply call `toupper()` which also requires the statement: `#include <ctype.h>`
4. when calling `scanf()` should always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.
5. the defined value `EXIT_SUCCESS` requires the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`
6. There are a lot less problems using `getchar()` rather than `scanf()`
7. it is usually a good idea to have the program pause before exiting so you can look at the results on the terminal
8. `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`
9. `toupper()` expects a `int` parameter and returns an `int`
10. EOF is a `int`, usually with the value `-1`

Suggest the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // getchar(), printf(), perror(), EOF
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <ctype.h>   // toupper(), isalpha(), isdigit(), ispunct()

int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    printf("Please enter characters. Press ENTER when you are finished\n");

    do
    {
        ch = getchar();

        if(    !isalpha( ch ) 
            && !isdigit( ch ) 
            && !ispunct( ch )
            && !('\n' == ch ) )
        {  // then not a printable char
            continue;
        }

        if( EOF ==  ch )
        {
            break;
        }

        ch = toupper(ch);
        printf("%c\n", ch);
    } while( '\n' != ch );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} // end function: main
```

Note: it would be a good idea to have the program pause, before exiting, so user can look at the output.